# Is that tire good to use?

Tags: tires, car

[image]

It had a small leak (32 PSI after two weeks became about 16 PSI).

The shop repaired it and now there is no leak for a few weeks, but I saw it stays expose from outside.

What is your opinion, may it need tracking?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If by "may it need ***tracking***" you are wondering if you need to pay attention to it, if it hasn't leaked any appreciable air in the last few weeks, it should be good to go. Since the damage is in the tread (albeit *near the edge* of the tire), as long as it can be patched, it's not leaking air, and there's no major deformation or bubbling of the rubber, you shouldn't have any issues with the tire. I'm not seeing an issue here, so my suggestion is to pay attention to it as you would at any other time: check the tire pressure of all your tires at least once a month to ensure proper inflation levels are kept.